# how to draw the starting degree from 6 o'clock instead of 3 o'clock

Tags: ios, core-graphics

i refered from this [example](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/how-to-build-a-custom-control-in-ios/)

i will like to draw the line from 6 o'clock instead of 3 o'clock

```
//Create the path
CGContextAddArc(ctx, self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2, radius, 0, M_PI *2, 0);

//Set the stroke color to black

[[UIColor colorWithRed:241.0/255.0 green:90.0/255.0 blue:36.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]setStroke];

//Define line width and cap
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, TB_BACKGROUND_WIDTH);
CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapButt);

//draw it!
//CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathFill);
CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathStroke);
```

currently
[image]

required to be like this drawing from 6 o'clock instead of 3 0'clock
[image]

Comment: Sorry @DavidRönnqvist, i'm new with Core Graphic and a math idiot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `CGContextAddArc()`, the method signature is as follow:

```
void CGContextAddArc (
   CGContextRef c,
   CGFloat x,
   CGFloat y,
   CGFloat radius,
   CGFloat startAngle,
   CGFloat endAngle,
   int clockwise
);
```

To modify the start position from 6 o'clock to 3 o'clock , that is to set the `startAngle` to -90 degree, which is :

```
angle in degree = angle in radian x 180 / M_PI
```

i.e.

```
-90 = radian x 180 / M_PI
radian = -90 x M_PI / 180
radian = -M_PI / 2
```

modify the 1st line as follow :

```
CGContextAddArc(ctx, self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2, radius, -M_PI/2, ToRad(270), 0);
```

*Note: the actual direction of the final path is dependent on the current transformation matrix of the graphics context.*

Comment: err after i sent it between 3 to 6 o'clock it no longer fill up ? am i missing something ?

Comment: all good now, i changed the ending angle from 0 to 270
 CGContextAddArc(imageCtx, self.frame.size.width/2  , self.frame.size.height/2, radius, -M_PI/2, ToRad(self.startAngle), 270);

Comment: wait. the last parameter is either `1` (clockwise) or `0` (anti-clockwise).